Como solucionar error con porcentajes en una matriz
Tengo el siguiente origen de datos donde tengo que contar por fecha de visita las veces que un proceso a pasado por cada mes en cada estado, aplicando como filtro principal la fecha de visita para el siguiente ejemplo lo hago con el mes de Abril.
El siguiente es el origen de datos que utilizo.
City        Location            Name            Visit Date  Status      Enroll Month Enroll Year
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Rhoda Horton    27-05-23    Open        May          2023   
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Rhoda Horton    27-05-23    Progress    May          2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Rhoda Horton    27-05-23    Canceled    May          2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Rhoda Horton    27-05-23    Closed      May          2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Barry Parrish   28-04-23    Open        April        2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Barry Parrish   28-04-23    Progress    April        2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Barry Parrish   28-04-23    Canceled    April        2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Barry Parrish   28-04-23    Closed      May          2023
Salt Lake   Red Butte Garden    Carolyn Hogan   25-04-23    Open        April        2023
Salt Lake   Red Butte Garden    Carolyn Hogan   25-04-23    Progress    May          2023
Salt Lake   Red Butte Garden    Carolyn Hogan   25-04-23    Canceled    May          2023
Salt Lake   Red Butte Garden    Carolyn Hogan   25-04-23    Closed      June         2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Farrah Gray     23-04-23    Open        April        2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Farrah Gray     23-04-23    Progress    August       2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Farrah Gray     23-04-23    Canceled    August       2023
Salt Lake   Capitol Building    Farrah Gray     23-04-23    Closed      August       2023

Para contar las veces que un proceso ha estado en cada mes segun la fecha de visita utilizo la siguiente medida:
Total Proc. Open = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[STATUS] = "Open")) 

Asi mismo con cada uno de los diferentes Status:
Total Proc. Progress = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[STATUS] = "Progress")) 
Total Proc. Canceled = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[STATUS] = "Canceled")) 
Total Proc. Closed = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[STATUS] = "Closed")) 

Para lograr que todos estos datos se ajusten a la matriz que estoy realizando utilizo una medida adicional en donde hago uso de un Switch:
Measure Status = 
    SWITCH(VALUES(Table1[STATUS]),
    "Open",[Total Proc. Open],
    "Progress",[Total Proc. Progress],
    "Canceled",[Total Proc. Canceled],
    "Closed",[Total Proc. Closed])

Hasta aqui todo me funciona correctamente y los datos se muestran correctamente como quiero en la siguiente matriz:

El error sucede cuando quiero mostrar en una nueva matriz los porcentajes de los datos anteriores, es decir, que deseo que se muesten de la siguiente manera:

Para el calculo de los porcentajes en la matriz, he hecho algo similar a la matriz anterior donde utilizo un Switch, la medida es la siguiente:
Porcentage Measure = 
    SWITCH(VALUES(Table1[STATUS]), 
    "Open","100%",
    "Progress",DIVIDE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[STATUS] = "Progress"),CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[STATUS] = "Open")),
    "Canceled",DIVIDE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[STATUS] = "Canceled"),CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[STATUS] = "Open")),
    "Closed",DIVIDE(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[STATUS] = "Closed"),CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table1),Table1[STATUS] = "Open")))

Al usar la medida anterior solamente me muestra los porcentajes del mes que tengo seleccionado en el filtro y no me muestra los demas, un ejemplo a continuacion de lo que se muestra es lo siguiente:

Hay algún cambio que deba realizar en mi medida para lograr el objetivo?
